# How to find normal distribution that has a quadratic?

Tags: probability, statistics, normal-distribution

Let $X$ be a normal random variable with mean 1 and variance 4. Find
$P(X^2 − 2X ≤ 8)$. (Answer key .86)

My attempt  $$P(X^2-2X\le 8)=P((X+2)(X-4)\le 0)$$ and this is where I am lost.  I did the following$$P(X\le -2)+P(X\le 4)=1$$ and noticed that answer is just $1$   by looking at the mean.  So I am doing something wrong.

Comment: What $X$ values satisfy $(X+2)(X-4)\le0$?  (NB it's not a probability question at this stage.)

Comment: @David Thank you.  It makes sense now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The condition $(X+2)(X−4) \leq 0$ is equivalent to $-2 \leq X \leq 4$.  Therefore,

$$
P[(X+2)(X−4) \leq 0] =  P[X \leq 4] - P[X < -2].
$$